# Trying to divide by solution of odeint

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, physics, odeint

I am using odeint in python to solve something (the Friedmann equation for a matter only universe) and it gives me the values of a that i want. However, how do i get it to return/plot (da/dt)/a? i.e how can divide the values for the function for the derivative by the corresponding values of the solution?

This is my attempted code: (ignore the earlier bits i.e the figure 1 plot; its the part with H i'm concerned about)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

t_0 = 0.0004
a_0 = 0.001
omega_m = 1.0 #for EdS
H_0 = 1./13.7

#the function for EdS universe
def Friedmann(a, t):
    dadt = H_0 * (omega_m)**(1./2.) * a**(-1./2.)
    return dadt

t = np.linspace(t_0,13.7,101)
a = odeint(Friedmann, a_0, t)
a = np.array(a).flatten()

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t, a)
plt.title("Einstein-de Sitter Universe")
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("a")

#comparing to analytic solution

an = (((3. / 2.) * (H_0 * omega_m**(1./2.)) * (t - t_0)) + a_0**(3. / 2.))**(2. / 3.)
an = np.array(an).flatten()
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t, a, t, an, "+")

H = [x/y for x, y in zip(Friedmann(a, t), a)]

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(t, H) 

plt.show()
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is exactly the error? Try `H = [ Friedmann(x,s)/x for x,s in zip(a,t) ]`.

Comment: I see no error, only a rather large first value in `H`. Either omit that by `plt.plot(t[1:], H[1:]);` or use a logarithmic scale in the vertical direction.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Omitting the first value worked, getting a much nicer plot now.